# IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace Yielding True when Text is ">="

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have a if statement that is doing validation for textbox on a WinForms application.

```
if (txtRule.Text.IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace())
{
    result = false;
    //error provider code
}
```

I know for a fact that the text in this textbox is the string ">=" because I'm using a breakpoint to figure out what the current text is in the textbox.

Obviously the text cannot be null since there is something in the textbox, and the same can be said about it not being empty. This means that is must be the case that the special characters ">=" are considered white space for some reason?

I would like to know the reason this if statement yields true when everything seems to be pointing towards a false value.

Comment: what is your `IsNullEmptyOrWhiteSpace()` method?

Comment: Did you write your own extension?  Better show us that code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering that there is no instance method with that name in the `System.String` class (the most similar by name is [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) that is `static`, while you are using your method on a `txtRule.Text` that is a `System.String`), then probably that is an extension method written by someone where you work. Try doing a Go To Definition and check.

Comment: Thank you for actually providing an answer instead of just blaming the post like most people do on StackOverflow. I didn't know that it was an extension method because someone else in the department wrote it. I just assumed it was a basic method off of string. Thanks again!